# youtube api filtered search

Tags: php, api, youtube, youtube-api

I have a music site that use Youtube Api. I want to filter the videos by size. Because when there is a high quality video, concert shows etc. streaming can hobble at low speed internet connections.
Also, i want to show pure music videos. I don't want show concert record, cover or remix etc. Which way do i fallow to filter original music records.

By the way search codes i am using are

```
 /*
$params: string, artist_name - song
returns an array >> video_id, video name, video length
*/      
function youtube_find_video($params)
{
    str_replace("'", "", $params);
    $q = preg_replace('/[[:space:]]/', '/', trim($params));
    $q = utf8_decode(utf8_encode($q));
    $replacements = array(',', '?', '!', '.');
    $q = str_replace($replacements, "", $q);
    $feedURL = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/-/{$q}?orderby=relevance&max-results=1";
    $sxml = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);
    if(!$sxml)
    {
        return false;
    }       
    else{
        $entry  = $sxml->entry;
        if(!$entry)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // get nodes in media: namespace for media information
        $media = $entry->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');

        if($media)
        {
            // get video player URL
            $attrs = $media->group->player->attributes();
            $url = $attrs['url'];
            if(!$url)
            {
                return false;
                break;
            }
            parse_str( parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_QUERY ), $my_array_of_vars );
            $watch['id'] = $my_array_of_vars['v'];

            // get video name
            $watch['name'] = $media->group->title;

            // get <yt:duration> node for video length[minute]
            $yt = $media->children('http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007');
            $attrs = $yt->duration->attributes();
            $watch['length'] = sprintf("%0.2f", $attrs['seconds']/60);

            $watch = simplexml_kurtul($watch); 
            return $watch;           
        }

        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What  is your question, what doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks :) That code works fine but i want to improve it. Which way do i fallow to filter original music videos? Not, concert, cover or remix. Just original pure music videos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to exclude HD videos from search results. Taken from docs:

> To only retrieve HD videos, set the `hd` parameter value to `true` or include the parameter in your request but do not specify a parameter value. Note that `false` is not a valid parameter value, and you cannot restrict search results to exclude HD videos. The API's default behavior is to return all videos, regardless of their resolution. In a video feed entry, the `<yt:hd>` tag indicates that a video contains HD content.

The YouTube player JavaScript API has a method for [setting the video quality](http://code.google.com/intl/fi-FI/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html#Playback_quality), which you could do upon video load.

It's not possible to exclude other than music videos either. However, you can search for videos uploaded only by YouTube partners, and that includes VEVO, as far as I know:

> The `uploader` parameter, which is only supported for search requests, lets you restrict a query to YouTube partner videos. A YouTube partner is a person or organization that has been accepted into and participates in the YouTube Partner Program. The uploader parameter's value must be `partner`.

All the options for searching videos are present [in the docs](http://code.google.com/intl/fi-FI/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html#Searching_for_videos).